# Android app won't open after updating on Google Play Store. Any tips on how to debug?

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I recently submitted an update of my app to the play store, and it worked fine when I installed it on my phone from my computer, but the app won't open if you download it from the app store.

I built the app in react native and between this update and the last the only differences are: I updated React Native (0.59.5 => 0.60.5) and I fixed a bug with AdMob so that ads now show. I've gotten rid of all the other changes I had made and it's still not working.

To fix it, I've tried building it in 1 apk (instead of separating it by architecture), building without progaurd, R8, or Hermes, double-checking that my signing is correct (although it shouldn't let me update if that's the problem), and making sure I'm using the newest play services.

Lastly, I'm not using any sign-in api (all the similar problems I've seen to this have been related to Google or Facebook sign-in).

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be or even how to debug it? Using `adb logcat` shows a bunch of logs and even after doing my best to sort through them, I can't find anything helpful. And using `react-native log-android` doesn't show anything at all.

The url for the app is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pulse.android54mp

Comment: Can you share google play store url of your application???

Comment: @VishalDhanotiya Sure! https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pulse.android54mp

Comment: Maybe you can consider adding Google Analytics to your code and find out the cause for the issue.

Comment: @sunilsunny I already have firebase analytics and crashlytics set up, but I'm not getting any crash reports. I'm not sure if its because the app is crashing before crashlytics starts running, or if I just didn't set up crashlytics correctly. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll look into getting crash reports now

Comment: Here's a good tip for when you're using logcat. It will spit out a ton of info when first connecting, after a couple seconds it starts to slow down. This is when you want to open your app and if needed ctrl+c out of logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being Hermes. If I disable that, it works fine when downloaded from the play store. I think the first time I tested disabling Hermes, I downloaded an older version of my app from the play store, thinking it was my newest release, which lead me to believe disabling it didn't make a difference.